# Query result from multiple tables display by row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 12 monthly tables and need to display one row from each table. If I try joining everything comes into one row. Can you please help me with a solution? I use ms sql.

Thanks 
Peter

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results (I would suggest showing fewer than 12 tables).  Why would you want one arbitrary row from each table?

Comment: `I have 12 monthly tables...` you lost me there; why not put all the data into a single table?

Comment: The columns are salesId, product, quantity and employee number . And there are 12 tables named like sales_jan, sales_feb to sales_dec.

Comment: @PeterJones why dont you add a colum in the table and calle it .. yearsale ?

Comment: What is the relation, how this tables can join each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table1
WHERE <codition_to_get_the_right_row>
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table2
WHERE <codition_to_get_the_right_row>
...
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table12
WHERE <codition_to_get_the_right_row>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your instant help

Comment: You are welcome. However it is quite bad design to have monthly tables. Most probably it is enough to have just 1 table and then use aggregations to get the needed 12 rows